# Angular 2 Nested Forms with common error handling not working

Tags: forms, angular

I have created a control-message component and validation service based on [this blog article](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management).  This works great for a component that is a single flat form. However, I what to use this control-message component within a nested form. That is, a form that is represented by two components, and outer and inner component. The outer component has the < form > tag and the inner component only has < input > fields. In my code, the control-message component does not work within the inner component. I get an error message like:

> EXCEPTION: Template parse errors: No provider for NgFormModel
>   ("holder="innerField1"/>  [ERROR ->] 
> "):
>   InnerFormComponent@5:4

I am using Angular 2.0.0 rc1.  The complete code is below. As is, the code is working because I have commented out the problem html line. Notice the line that says < !-- THE LINE BELOW WHEN UNCOMMENTED CAUSES TEMPLATE PARSE ERROR -- > When the line below that is uncommented, the aforementioned error will appear.

Below is the complete code. If you have a standard angular2 starter project, you can replace app.component.ts with this code and it should work.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Host } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators, ControlGroup, FORM_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgFormModel , Control, FORM_PROVIDERS}    from '@angular/common';

// ValidationService from https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management
export class ValidationService {

  static getValidatorErrorMessage(code: string) {
    let config = {
      'required': 'Required',
      'invalidEmailAddress': 'Invalid email address',
    }

    return config[code];
  }

  static emailValidator(control : Control) {
    // RFC 2822 compliant regex
    if (control.value.match(/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/)) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return { 'invalidEmailAddress': true };
    }
  }
}

// control-message component from https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-form-builder-and-validation-management
@Component({
  selector: 'control-messages',
  template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ControlMessages {
  @Input() controlName: string;

  constructor(@Host() private _formDir: NgFormModel) {
    console.log("obj="+_formDir);

  }

  get errorMessage() {
    // Find the control in the Host (Parent) form
    let c = this._formDir.form.find(this.controlName);

    for (let propertyName in c.errors) {
      // If control has a error
      if (c.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && c.touched) {
        // Return the appropriate error message from the Validation Service
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}

// Inner Form Component THAT DOESN'T WORK when the marked lines below are uncommented. Why? Why? Why?
@Component({
  selector: 'inner-form',
  providers:[FORM_PROVIDERS, NgFormModel],
  directives:[CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, ControlMessages],
  template: `
    <p>InnerForm</p>
    <label for="innerField1"> if1: </label>
    <input [ngFormControl]="innerField1" placeholder="innerField1"/>
    <!-- THE LINE BELOW WHEN UNCOMMENTED CAUSES TEMPLATE PARSE ERROR -->
    <!-- <control-messages controlName="innerField1" ></control-messages> -->
    <br>`
})
export class InnerFormComponent  implements OnInit {

  @Input() group: ControlGroup;

  innerField1 = new Control('', Validators.required);

  constructor(@Host() private formX : NgFormModel){
    console.log("formx= " + this.formX);
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log("valid = " + this.group);
    this.group.addControl('innerField1', this.innerField1);
  }
}

// Outer Form Component
@Component({
  selector: 'outer-form',
  directives:[CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, InnerFormComponent, ControlMessages],
  providers: [NgFormModel],
  template: `
  <p>Outer Form</p>
  <form [ngFormModel]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <br>
    <label for="field1"> Field1: </label>
    <input [ngFormControl]="form.controls['field1']" placeholder="field1" id="field1"/>
    <control-messages controlName="field1" ></control-messages>
    <br>
    <inner-form [group]="inner"> </inner-form>
  <br>
  <button type="submit" >Submit</button>  
</form>`
})
export class OuterFormComponent {

  form : ControlGroup;
  inner: ControlGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){
    this.inner = this.formBuilder.group({});
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      "field1": ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSubmit(){
    console.log("submitted: "  + JSON.stringify(this.form.value));
    console.log("submitted: "  + JSON.stringify(this.inner.value));
  }
}

// app component
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<outer-form></outer-form>',
  directives: [OuterFormComponent]

})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Here a [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/70UxQgfKcAl34CANQTRB?p=preview%20To%20make%20the%20error%20occur,%20uncomment%20line%2021%20of%20app/inner-form.component.ts) to a plunker with this code:

Comment: Try removing `NgFormModel` from providers at `InnerFormComponent`, since you're injecting them in `OuterFormComponent` they might be different instances (providers are inherited). If that doens't work, can you make a plunker with your code?

Comment: I will make a plunker...

Comment: Plunker link added. http://plnkr.co/edit/70UxQgfKcAl34CANQTRB?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot providers for ControlMessages component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'control-messages',
  template: `<div *ngIf="errorMessage !== null">{{errorMessage}}</div>`
})
export class ControlMessages {
  @Input() controlName: string;

  constructor(@Host() private _formDir: NgFormModel) {
    console.log("obj="+_formDir);

  }

  get errorMessage() {
    // if you try to access form before it's initialized you'll have error
    if (this._formDir.form === null) return; // <-- INIT TOO EARLY

    // Find the control in the Host (Parent) form
    let c = this._formDir.form.find(this.controlName);
    if (c === null) return; // <-- INIT TOO EARLY

    for (let propertyName in c.errors) {
      // If control has a error
      if (c.errors.hasOwnProperty(propertyName) && c.touched) {
        // Return the appropriate error message from the Validation Service
        return ValidationService.getValidatorErrorMessage(propertyName);
      }
    }

    return null;
  }
}


// app component
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<outer-form></outer-form>',
  directives: [OuterFormComponent],
  providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS, NgFormModel]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Here's [**updated plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/a8mfyJyCEJLdmpX4XReG?p=preview) without errors - I moved providers to `AppComponent` and removed them from other places... It works now, you can try moving them to other place, if you want...

Comment: Although that makes the error go away, it also causes the control-messages component to stop working. I'm not yet an expert, but I think that directive causes the control-message component to create a new NgFormModel instance every time its invoked. So of course it always now can satisfy its need. But a new NgFormModel isn't what's desired. Would like the parent's NgFormModel to be used.

Comment: @RanchoSoftware Updated the answer, I made it work somehow (;

Comment: Thanks Sasxa. You put me on the right path. I now have working control-messages component (and validation) for both outer and inner forms. I've been trying to make this work for a few days now.